# Three.js line does not work in Canvas renderer but works in WebGL renderer

Tags: webgl, three.js

I would like to use Canvas renderer on non WebGL browsers and WebGL on others.
My code works fine with webGL renderer but with canvas renderer the THREE.Line doesn't shows.

```
//Edges
var edgeMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    opacity: 0.6
} );

for (var edgeId in graph.edgesl) {

    var nodeInId = graph.edgesl[edgeId];
    var nodeOutId = graph.edgesr[edgeId];

    var edgeGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
    edgeGeom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(nodes[nodeInId].position));
    edgeGeom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(nodes[nodeOutId].position));

    var drawingLine = new THREE.Line( edgeGeom , edgeMat );

    //Store In, Out node ID
    drawingLine.inNodeId = nodeInId;
    drawingLine.outNodeId = nodeOutId;

    nodes[nodeInId].edges.push(drawingLine);
    nodes[nodeOutId].edges.push(drawingLine);

    //Meshes additionally need also dynamic flag enabled (to keep internal typed arrays).
    drawingLine.dynamic = true;

    scene.addObject(drawingLine );

    edges.push(drawingLine);

}
```

Anyone has any ideas for this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From r45 `scene.addObject(drawingLine);` must be now `scene.add(drawingLine);`

Same issue here:

[Three.js not scaling or rotating Mesh on render()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280541/three-js-not-scaling-or-rotating-mesh-on-render)